# Need reputation so I can join the chat beta

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I need 20 reputation so I can join the chat beta. Can someone help?

Comment: Earning reputation on Meta is not the hardest thing. Also, if you have an account on one of the other sites with 200 of reputation, it gives you 100 on the other sites, including this one. Begging for reputation, even for testing purposes, is not an appropriate way to get it.

Answer (score 3):

You can join without having 20 reputation, you just won't be able to talk